# The blessing and the sorrow in Proverbs 10:22

Tags: proverbs

In Proverbs 10:22 it reads:

> The **blessing** from the LORD makes a person rich, and he adds no **sorrow** to it.
>   (Proverbs 10:22, NET, emphasis mine)

> The **blessing** of the Lord is upon the head of a righteous person;
>   it enriches, and **grief of heart** will not be added to it.
>   (Proverbs 10:22, NETS, emphasis mine)

Is it *possible* that a blessing includes also the sorrow? How should one interpret this verse?

Answer (score 2):

From the Lexham Hebrew interlinear Bible we can see that the sorrow is specifically prevented (not added) while the riches are added:

[image]

Therefore it stands to reason that when God physically blesses a godly person, he also takes care of the soul and prevents many sorrows, curses and temptations that would often accompany the outward prosperity of the ungoldly.

Comment: Thank you for the translation, @Mike - it was very easy to follow (once I realised to read it right to left!) The blessing of the Lord enriches without sorrow - I think this 'sorrow' refers more to the uneasiness in the heart (whenever wealth or gain is obtained without integrity, generosity and compassion) that isn't present when we have acted honourably and genuinely considered the wellbeing of all parties that may be impacted (including the environment, etc). It's not a way to judge 'the ungodly', but a call to closely observe our own hearts.

Answer (score -1):

From a personal perspective, it means that there is no "catch" to it or conditions that would be added to it. The gospel is a blessing like this in that after we are adopted in Christ, we don't have to do anything to keep our salvation or earn favor with God. No additions or conditions.